# ActiveModel Serializer with has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers, rails-api

I have a model called Event.  An Event `has_and_belongs_to_many :event_sub_categories` and a EventSubCategory `has_and_belongs_to_many :events`.  I have the following action:

```
def index
    @events = Event.where(begins_at: DateTime.now.beginning_of_day..1.week.from_now).group_by{|e| e.begins_at.beginning_of_day}.to_a.to_json
    render json: @events
end
```

The action returns the data exactly as needed except for one problem, it doesn't have subcategories.  I need the json to contain the subcategories.  I tried making the following ActiveModel Serializer:

```
 class EventSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id, :name, :event_sub_categories
 end
```

but the serializer above doesn't change the json at all.  How do I fix this?

Comment: What are `subcategories` and how do they relate to `events`?

Comment: I updated the question.  Sorry, I messed up when I wrote it and put in "patient" when i meant "event_sub_category".  The question should be clearer now.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
class EventSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name 
  has_many :event_sub_categories
end
```

Comment: i think you should remove the to_json in `@events = Event.where(begins_at: DateTime.now.beginning_of_day..1.week.from_now).group_by{|e| e.begins_at.beginning_of_day}.to_a.to_json`, because the activemodelserializer automatically handle it for you

Comment: are you using the full rails or rails api?

Comment: This answer is right, along with removing `.to_a.to_json` at the end of the first line of your method. AMS will not kick-in if you call `to_json` on your model(s).

Comment: I need it in an array.  Angular on the client side needs an array.  Also, removing .to_a.to_json doesn't fix it anyway :(

Comment: It's the group_by that is doing it, but I NEED the information to be grouped this way.

Comment: Whatever you do, calling `to_json` on the _resource_ will make it so that _no AMS code is being called_. Your call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1- In your controller modify the query in a way it includes the event_sub_categories:

```
def index
    @events = Event.includes(:event_sub_categories).where(begins_at: DateTime.now.beginning_of_day..1.week.from_now).group_by{|e| e.begins_at.beginning_of_day}.to_a.to_json
    render json: @events
end
```

2- create a Serializer for EventSubCategory model

3- in your Event serializer create the method event_sub_categories

```
class EventSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
   attributes :id, :name, :event_sub_categories

   def event_sub_categories
     object.event_sub_categories.map do |sub_category|
       EventSubCategorySerializer.new(sub_category)
     end
   end
 end
```